# How to do head cleaning of the printer?

Tags: ubuntu, printing

I having **Epson L130** printer.

I know my printer model is old, but it is my old printer, I wanted to use it but it is kinda light and is missing some colours while printing, Head cleaning always solve this problem.

When I was on Windows, I was able to do head cleaning but as soon as I switched to **Ubuntu 20.04**, I am not getting any option for that. I have installed driver for the printer from web through Epson official website, It is printing documents and other stuff, so the driver is working, but I cannot see any head cleaning option and also maybe I need to do power ink flushing.

Is there some way to do that? I searched everything but didn't find correct  solution.

Can I do it using some sort of other software or via terminal? I would prefer using terminal. Its been 1 year since I switched to Ubuntu, so I am definitely having some knowledge, so terminal would be much better.

Yes, my printer supports automatic head cleaning and its a wired printer btw.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: is it a network printer?

Comment: why don't you use the printer control panel to do head cleaning?

Comment: @jsotola Where is it how to access it ??

Comment: @jsotola I am new to printers in ubuntu

Comment: it is on the printer, not in ubuntu

Comment: @jsotola It is a non smart inkjet printer Epson L130 , It supports head cleaning .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130310/discussion-between-akshaj-singla-and-jsotola).